# Match Two Sets of Different Consecutive Numbers Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I am classifying a list of vanity phone numbers based on their patterns using regex.

I would like to capture this pattern `5ABXXXYYY`

Sample `534666999`

I wrote the below regex that captures `XXXYYY`.

```
(\d)\1{2}(\d)\2{2}
```

I want to add a condition to assert the `B` is not the same number as `X`.

Desired output will match the given pattern exactly and replace it with the word silver.

```
S_2 = 534666999
S_2_pattern = re.sub(r"(\d)\2{2}(\d)\3{2}", "Silver", str(S_2))
print(S_2_pattern)
Silver
```

Thanks

Comment: This part `(\d)\2{2}(\d)\3{2}` matches 6 digits, how would that consume all characters in a 9 digits string like `534666999`. You want to also match any preceding digits but there must not be nother `6` before `666` ? Please try to explain better.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my first language. You understanding is correct. I want to match all 9 digits according the given conditions then replace the pattern -if matched- with the word silver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match 9 digits, and the 3rd digit should not be the same as the 4th, you can add another capture group for the 3rd digit and all the group numbers after are incremented by 1.

```
\b\d\d(\d)(?!\1)(\d)\2\2(\d)\3\3\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d\d` Match 2 digits
- `(\d)(?!\1)` Capture a single digit in group 1, and assert that it is not followed by the same
- `(\d)\2\2` Capture a single digit in group 2 and match 2 times the same digits after it
- `(\d)\3\3` Capture a single digit in group 3 and match 2 times the same digits after it
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvEZTK/1)

If the first 3 digits in group 2 should also be different from the last 3 digits in group 3:

```
\b\d\d(\d)(?!\1)(\d)(?!\d\d\2)\2\2(\d)\3\3\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UncJYB/1)